# How to add a subquery in the JSON object to insert into a table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to insert rows into a table :

```
router.post('/insertAllAccessible', function(req, res) {
                                                                // récupération des organisations accessibles
                                                                connexion.query("select organisation_id, id_tag_ip, organisation_lib from organisation where is_accessible = 1", (err, rows, fields) => {
                                                                    if (err) {
                                                                        throw err;
                                                                    }
                                                                    for(var d=0; d<rows.length; d++) {
                                                                        var json = rows[d];
                                                                        idOrganisations.push(json.id_tag_ip);
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                                request({
                                                                            headers: req.body,
                                                                            url: "https://api.tag-ip.com/track/fleets",
                                                                            json: true
                                                                        }, function (error, response, body) {
                                                                                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                                                                    var flottes = body.data;
                                                                                    for(var f=0; f<flottes.length; f++) {
                                                                                        var flotteJSON = flottes[f];
                                                                                        var relationshipsJSON = flotteJSON.relationships;
                                                                                        var organizationJSON = relationshipsJSON.organization;
                                                                                        var dataJSON = organizationJSON.data;
                                                                                        var attributesJSON = flotteJSON.attributes;
                                                                                        // filtrage des flottes selon les organisations accessibles
                                                                                        if ( idOrganisations.includes(dataJSON.id) ) {
                                                                                            var oFlotte = {"organisation_id":"(select organisation_id from organisation where id_tag_ip = '"+dataJSON.id+"')",
                                                                                                           "flotte_tag_ip_id":dataJSON.id,
                                                                                                           "flotte_libelle":attributesJSON.name,
                                                                                                           "flotte_description":attributesJSON.description};
                                                                                            connexion.query("insert into flotte set ?", oFlotte, function(err, rows) {
                                                                                                                                                    if (err) throw err;
                                                                                                                                                 }
                                                                                                            );
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        );
                                                            }
            );
```

In runtime it bugs ! So what is wrong ?

Comment: try moving the `request()` block inside your first query's callback. What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: I get the same error : `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`